# how to overwrite terraform elb listener resource

Tags: terraform

I have defined a ELB resource with a listener in my terraform and now in my module, I am using that resource to overide some variables.

It is possible to overide a listener (https) in my resource.

like

```
service.tf
resource "aws_elb" "main" {
 listener {
}
}

now in my module
module "test" {
source = "./service"

}
```

Here in my module, I need to override this resource listener, how can I do that?

Comment: You should really show your module definition as well but no you can't just override a resource like that and would instead create another resource. Why can't you make your listener configurable by the module instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You'll have to pass the variables between modules. In the source module, create an output and then in the receiving module create a variable and set it to the output of the source.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#listener

https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html